# How to compile Boost library with Visual Studio 2022 ( Preview 3)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

Apparently vc143 is unsupported and i cannot seem to make the toolset commands to work
with the following commands in powershell:

./bootstrap.bat gcc
OR
./bootstrap.bat mingw
OR
./bootstrap.bat msvc

Boost version is 1.77

Regards,
Usman

Comment: "cannot seem to make the toolset commands to work" please show the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: `PS F:\boost_1_77_0\boost_1_77_0> ./bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Build engine
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Usman\AppData\Local
Found with vswhere F:\vs
###
### "Unknown toolset: vcunk"
###
### You can specify the toolset as the argument, i.e.:
###     .\build.bat msvc
###
### Toolsets supported by this script are: borland, como, gcc,
###     gcc-nocygwin, intel-win32, mingw,
###     vc12, vc14, vc141, vc142
###
### If you have Visual Studio 2017 installed you will need to either update
### the Visual Studio 2017 installer or r
###

`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add this information there.

Answer (score 9):

[Implemented VS2022 vc143 support](https://github.com/boostorg/config/pull/405) since [boost version 1.78.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_78_0.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30375676)

Comment: Downloaded  boost_1_78_0.7z. It does not have the build.bat that is called by bootstrap.bat.

Answer (score 6):

I have made it work, but it requires a lot of changes to a few files in order to make it work.

I've put my procedure here:
https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/552

Hopefully someone can include the changes into Boost itself.

Answer (score 5):

Now that VS 2022 is released and the version of Boost is boost_1_79_0 the process is simple.

1. Download the windows boost libraries from https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_79_0.html
2. Unzip to a path of your choice for eg E:\boost_1_79_0
3. Open Developer Command Prompt For VS 2022 and cd into extracted boost directory
4. Issue the command **bootstrap vc143** hit Enter and wait
5. Next issue the command **.\b2** hit Enter and grab tea or coffee.

On successful completion the above procedure will build boost static libraries found in eg E:\boost_1_79_0\stage\lib

Hope it helps.