# Unable to build boost on windows 10/Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, build

I have been trying to build boost on windows 10 using visual studio, but unable to build

```
Found with vswhere C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
###
### "Unknown toolset: vcunk"
###
### You can specify the toolset as the argument, i.e.:
###     .\build.bat msvc
###
### Toolsets supported by this script are: borland, como, gcc,
###     gcc-nocygwin, intel-win32, metrowerks, mingw,
###     vc12, vc14, vc141, vc142
###
### If you have Visual Studio 2017 installed you will need to either update
### the Visual Studio 2017 installer or run from VS 2017 Command Prompt
### as we where unable to detect your toolset installation.
###

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
```

I am using developer command prompt for VS 2022

**Command used**: bootstrap, bootstrap vc143, etc.

Comment: What release of boost are you building? I would expect it to have to be a very recent one for this to work.  Edit: this question seems to say that boost-1.78.0 or newer is required: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68935077/how-to-compile-boost-library-with-visual-studio-2022-preview-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68935077/how-to-compile-boost-library-with-visual-studio-2022-preview-3)

Comment: I am trying to build 1.75.0.

Comment: That is the problem. It's too old to have support for building using VS2022.

Comment: Which VS version will support 1.75.0 build. I want to build it from inside IDE. I have tried building it with VS2019. I was Unable to build it from inside IDE, but when I try to build it using VS19 developer command line it starts, but gets stuck at some point, and won’t proceed from there

Comment: I believe 1.75.0 should build with Visual Studio 2019 from the developer command prompt. You may have to run the `bjam.exe` command more than 1 time but it should finish.